# Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?

Tags: поддержка, faq, stackoverflow, нытьё

Меня очень часто спрашивают: “Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?”

Большинства пользователей Stack Overflow на русском прекрасно знают о весе и значение проекта в жизни русскоязычного сообщества программистов. Данное сообщение в первую очередь написано для новых пользователей, которые только хотят присоединиться к Stack Overflow на русском. Сообщение постоянно пополняется новыми ответами, по мере получения вопросов о проекте. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь их задавать!

#### Содержание

- [Что такое Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/174/6)
- [Почему так плохо без Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/175/6)
- [Stack Overflow на русском это как Stack Overflow, но только для программистов, которые не знают английского?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/176/6)
- [Знатоки отвечают только на английском, кто же поможет мне на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/177/6)
- [Почему на Stack Overflow на русском будет высокий уровень качества обсуждений без спама и ругани?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/178/6)
- [Зачем мне Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/179/6)
- [Почему не остаться на старом уютном “неформальном” форуме?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/180/6)
- [Как я могу помочь проекту?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/181/6)
- [Историческая сноска. Что за ХэшКод?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/182/6)

Answer (score 26):

#### Stack Overflow на русском это как Stack Overflow, но только для программистов, которые не знают английского?

Данное заблуждение достаточно плотно засело в сообществе, но оно ложно! Попробуйте ответить себе на следующий вопрос: почему при встрече с коллегой в коридоре мы используем русский язык, задавая вопрос по проекту? Мы вдруг на время перестали быть профессиональными программистами? Нет! Просто на русском языке это делать эффективнее. КПД от общения на иностранном языке будет всегда ниже.

Сейчас типичный русскоязычный разработчик находится в ситуации, подобной той, в которой были его англоязычные коллеги. До появления Stack Overflow было достаточно форумов, но все они были неэффективными. Русскоязычные программисты должны выбирать, где лучше получить ответ. Задавая вопрос на Stack Overflow, они вряд ли руководствуются распространенным заблуждением, что общаться на русском языке непрофессионально. Скорее, они просто хотят получить лучшее решение как можно быстрее, то есть эффективнее решить поставленную задачу. Язык тут ни при чем. Главное - это КПД.

КПД? Да, именно коэффициент полезного действия является решающим фактором. Процитирую коллегу.

Проведем аналогию, близкую нашей профессии, между работой человеческого мозга и вычислительной машины. В процессе производства микропроцессоров на фабрике чистая кремниевая пластина превращается в готовое изделие. Представим два существенно отличающихся процессора: ARM и Intel x86. Оба они имеют свои достоинства и недостатки и используются в различных, зачастую непересекающихся сферах. Оба вследствие различного устройства имеют различный язык машинных команд. И этот язык не может быть изменен. Если возникает необходимость выполнить машинный код одного процессора на другом, используется дополнительное программное (а иногда и аппаратное) обеспечение - эмулятор. Этот эмулятор всегда расходует дополнительные ресурсы системы на трансляцию из одного набора команд в другой набор команд. Издержки могут быть минимизированы, но они всегда есть. КПД системы с эмулятором всегда ниже, чем системы без эмулятора. Поэтому всегда, когда это возможно, таких систем стараются избегать.

В процессе развития человеческого организма мозг ребенка, воспринимая язык окружения, необратимо меняется. Родной язык становится "машинным кодом", который уже более невозможно изменить. А изучение иностранного языка - это создание и оптимизация "эмулятора", который транслирует понятия из иностранного языка в родной. Как и в случае вычислительной машины, система иностранный язык - родной язык  работает с пониженным КПД. Поэтому человек, мыслящий на иностранном языке, всегда добьется меньшего, чем человек, мыслящий на родном языке. Это может быть оправдано тогда и только тогда, когда не мыслить на иностранном невозможно.

Многие компании думают так же. Например, крупнейшая библиотека для разработчиков MSDN последовательно переводит всю новую документацию на наиболее значимые языки, в числе которых есть и русский.

Stack Overflow на русском - это наш общий шанс создать свободно распространяемую базу прикладных знаний, а также стандарт общения, благодаря которому мы сможем улучшить КПД всей IT-отрасли в целом.

---

[О решении руководства Stack Exchange открывать Stack Overflow на разных языках (англ.)](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/).

Comment: Хочу заметить, что "библиотека для разработчиков MSDN последовательно переводит всю новую документацию на наиболее значимые языки",  а  stackoverflow не переводит! А значит, что некоторые вопросы будут отвечены в одном языке но не в другом.

Answer (score 15):

#### Знатоки отвечают только на английском, кто же поможет мне на русском?

Еще один миф об отсутствии знатоков в русскоязычном сообществе, которые предпочитают общаться на своем первом языке. Уверен, каждый сам принимает решение — быть частью сообщества Stack Overflow на русском или нет. Мы лишь рекомендуем посетить [страницу лучших участников проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all). Например, обратите внимание на ответы пользователя [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) (к примеру, [его первый ответ в списке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/)). Я за свою карьеру не видел настолько талантливого и увлеченного специалиста. И он не один:  [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim), [Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley), [Deonis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4058/deonis), [avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp), [knes](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2825/knes) и многие другие. Это не просто увлеченные программисты — это энциклопедии прикладных знаний. Если, имея таких знатоков, кто-то не может получить ответ на вопрос, то проблема в вопросе, а не в языке, на котором он задан.

Comment: А я все же считаю, что надо привлекать сюда пользователей с оригинального SO. Я вот, лично, часто отвечаю на вопросы на английском SO, но зайдя сюда мне прям стало не по себе. Вопросы, которые давным давно бы закрыли на enSO, живут припеваюче здесь. С ответами то же самое. Уже не раз встречал, что в ответе пишут то, что должно быть в комментах. На enSO за такое сразу минусят прилично. Но здесь же такие ответы плюсуют, а иногда и вовсе делают правильными ответами. Не хватает пользователей со стажем, которые бы всем рулили.

Comment: "Не хватает пользователей со стажем, которые бы всем рулили." - эта фраза просто жутко огорчила. Ваша идея - это навязывание собственного представления о вещах всему сообществу. Ключевое слово здесь "навязывание". Если вам так не нравится русско-язычное сообщество - нет никаких причин вам в нем состоять. Идея сообщества, как я ее понимаю, состоит в том, чтоб все принимали участие в решении того, каким ему быть. Русско-язычное сообщество идет другим путем - и это нормально. Есть бесконечное количество правильных путей. Давайте просто выберем один из них. СОВМЕСТНО.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov *Вопросы, которые давным давно бы закрыли на enSO, живут припеваюче здесь.* - это может быть причиной перехода оттуда сюда, т.к. там начинают зажираться и перебирать харчами. Начнут и тут зажираться - и отсюда повалят.

Comment: Ну как миф? Если у меня узкоспециализированный вопрос и а русской версии по этой метке 6 вопросов, а в английской несколько тысяч, логично же, что там я быстрее найду ответ?

Answer (score 13):

#### Почему так плохо без Stack Overflow на русском?

Вспомните, сколько раз через поисковик вы находили ответ на Stack Overflow? А теперь вспомните свои чувства, когда в поисковой выдаче не было Stack Overflow? Честно, полезна ли такая выдача вообще?

Именно эти чувства испытывают день за днем многие ваши коллеги, для кого существует языковой барьер. И это был только поиск! А как насчет тех, кто хочет задать вопрос? Более того, как быть тем, кто стремится бесплатно поделиться знаниями с вами, чтобы решение *вашей* следующей задачи заняло на порядок меньше времени?

В большинстве случаев даже небольшой языковой барьер, присущий каждому живущему не в англоязычной среде, служит тем самым фактором, который препятствует профессиональному общению.

Сегодня в пространстве русского языка нет стандарта для обмена знаниями среди разработчиков, такого как Stack Overflow для англоязычных коллег. Конечно, в Рунете существует несколько аналогов, но, смотря правде в глаза, ни один из них не получил такого же широкого признания, как Stack Overflow.

**Настало время создать этот самый стандарт!**

Уверен, профессиональное общение на русском языке будет приятно и полезно не только людям с языковым барьером, но и для пользователей, свободно владеющих английским. Ведь Stack Overflow на русском - это наш шанс сделать пространство русского языка богаче. Общими усилиями мы сможем повысить не только свою производительность как разработчиков, но и культуру общения всего Рунета!

Answer (score 9):

#### Зачем мне Stack Overflow на русском?

**Зачем мне задавать вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском?**

Лучшим вознаграждением за вопрос, конечно же, будет развернутый правильный ответ!

**Зачем мне делиться знаниями на Stack Overflow на русском?**

Чтобы помочь коллегам именно в ту минуту, когда им так необходима рука поддержки!

Вопрос на Stack Overflow на русском - это не просто помощь одному человеку, это прежде всего вклад в свободно распространяемую базу прикладных знаний, которую смогут повторно использовать тысячи разработчиков, столкнувшись с аналогичной проблемой в будущем.

Answer (score 9):

#### Почему не остаться на старом уютном неформальном форуме?

Скорее всего, вы найдете Stack Overflow на русском полезным для себя, если вы программист или системный администратор и:

- вы ищете новые интересные вопросы;
- у вас есть конкретный вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию, на который вы бы хотели получить экспертный ответ;
- вы хотите поделиться с коллегам своими знаниями и опытом;
- вы хотите собрать решения задач в одном месте, избегая дубликатов;
- вы хотите принять участие в создании бесплатной свободно распространяемой базы прикладных знаний;
- вы не хотите, чтобы кто-то тратил огромное количество времени на поиск ответов уже решённых задач.

Скорее всего, вы найдёте Stack Overflow на русском полезным для себя, если вы хотите избежать:

- критику вместо ответов;
- грубость, шум и спам;
- трёп не по делу и “за жизнь”;
- лентяев школьников/студентов и их домашние задания;
- беспощадных вопросов: “Как стать программистом за N дней?”, “Как создать свой стартап в 15 лет?”, “Какую литературу читать, если ты ничего не знаешь?”, “У меня есть компьютер. Как на нём написать GTA5?” и подобных им.

В дополнение, Stack Overflow на русском, как и Stack Overflow на английском, работает на лучшем на сегодняшний день движке форумов вопросов и ответов, который постоянно улучшается.

Answer (score 9):

#### Как я могу помочь проекту?

Конечно, мы будем признательны за рекомендации сообщества Stack Overflow на русском друзьям, но для проекта нет ничего лучше, чем ваша реальная помощь коллегам в изучении программирования и системного администрирования: задавайте интересные вопросы, публикуйте полезные ответы, делитесь знаниями и опытом в формате вопросов и ответов.

Answer (score 7):

#### Что такое Stack Overflow на русском?

Stack Overflow на русском - это сообщество начинающих и опытных программистов, а также системных администраторов. Проект призван решить важные задачи, существующие в русскоязычном профессиональном IT-сообществе:

- создание стандарта общения такого же уровня<sup>1</sup> как на Stack Overflow на английском языке;
- создание свободно распространяемой базы прикладных знаний, помогающей решать повседневные задачи на порядок эффективнее за счет повторного использования существующих решений аналогичных проблем.

<sub>1 — речь идет именно об уровне качества и эффективности стандарта, но не о слепом копировании.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

#### Почему на Stack Overflow на русском будет высокий уровень качества обсуждений без спама и ругани?

Сообщество - это в первую очередь люди. Именно от участников зависит культура общения. Мы пригласили принять участие в проект всех пользователей ХэшКода, а также русскоязычных пользователей Stack Overflow. Их опыт использования сайта, авторитет и знания помогут Stack Overflow на русском стать лучшим местом в пространстве русского языка для того, чтобы получить ответ на вопрос по программированию или системному администрированию. К тому же, над проектом будет работать команда, которая создала англоязычное сообщество Stack Overflow.

Уверен, найдутся многие профессиональные разработчики программного обеспечения и системные администраторы, для которых русский язык играет важную роль в жизни. Вместе мы сможем создать наш общий остров знаний в океане Интернета!

Answer (score 6):

#### Историческая сноска. Что за ХэшКод?

Мы все прекрасно знаем, как необходимы знатоки, готовые делиться экспертизой с сообществом, и энтузиасты, которые задают интересные вопросы, стремясь к новым знаниям, как к солнцу! Именно такие люди собрались на ХэшКоде - русскоязычном аналоге Stack Overflow.

ХэшКод выделялся среди остальных форумов не только качественным содержимым, но и профессиональным сообществом знатоков, которое на протяжении нескольких лет помогало находить решения тысячам программистов. С самой первой минуты Stack Overflow на русском вы сможете получить ответ на ваш вопрос или поделиться знаниями!