# Информация к размышлению: падение интереса старожил Хэшкода

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, раньше-было-лучше

Обратил внимание, что последнее время в ответах редко встречаются популярные ранее ники. Провёл небольшое исследование.

Из 36 участников с наибольшим рейтингом за всё время (просто такое количество отображается у меня на одной странице) за последние 5 дней посетили сайт 18. На страницы наиболее активных (по набранному рейтингу) участников за год, квартал, месяц и неделю из них попали соответственно 13, 10, 9 и 8.

Так вот, за эти 5 дней только 10 человек из них отвечали на вопросы (комментировали что-либо 11), причём только двое ответили более чем на 5 вопросов (и четверо сделали больше пяти комментариев).

Мне кажется, что налицо падение интереса старожилов ХК к сайту. Возможно стоит обсудить какие именно факторы влияют на это и представляют ли они угрозу развитию ru.SO.

Comment: Старички большого СО тоже сюда заглядывают. И тоже убегают. Просто вопросы настолько бессмысленные и беспощадные, что отвечать нет желания. Сегодня заглядывал в список последних вопросов — из 50 было заминусовано 22, причём сурово так заминусовано. Десяток закрытых, ещё десяток на пути к закрытию. Вот и вся история.

Comment: Нытье - отличный тег =)

Comment: @avp: предлагаю переименовать тему, чтобы название отражало суть - "Последнее время в ответах редко встречаются популярные ранее ники - падение интереса старожил?"

Comment: А как дела обстоят на других сайтах сети, каков процент активных старожил?

Comment: @KromStern, заходите на сайт, сотня-другая кликов и инфа у вас в карамане.

Comment: @Discord, а может применить парадоксальное решение с "заминусованными" вопросами? Минусовать (тем более закрывать) вопросы могут только участники с репой больше (3000?) или репой (1000?) по любой из меток вопроса. Мне кажется обилие "назначенных плохими" (минусованные и замороженные) вопросов на главной странице просто сразу отбивает желание задавать любые  вопросы (и тем более отпугивает адекватных новичков). / Вот к примеру, мное недавно захотелось расширить ряд `tiny,small,normal,large,huge` на 4 промежуточные позиции, но после некоторого размышления *не решился* задать этот вопрос здесь.

Comment: @avp А топы (ака активные юзеры) как раз и минусуют.

Comment: @Discord, откуда такие сведения? Кстати, я имею в виду топов, заканчивающихся  `dzhioev 7,814` (Вам, Athari, уже недалеко) / Если серьезно, то минусов  вообще не так уж много (сейчас из 50 всего 4 вопроса). Наверное, основная проблема "дедов" не в этом. А вот в чем? Напрашивается, конечно, ответ -- "у каждого своя", но вот насколько он верен...

Comment: Опять же, интересно, **вот этот вопрос за что минусуют?** /  Кто-нибудь из минусующих может разумно (без формальных отсылок к правилам) прокомментировать свои действия?

Comment: @avp http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/300464/most-evil-users — отсортируйте по колонке Down. / Вопрос минусуют, потому что не согласны с вами.

Comment: @Discord, если правильно понял, то это обобщенная за все время статистика. А можете сделать, скажем, за последние полгода? / Нда... Несогласны с цифрами или вскрываевымым нарывом?

Comment: @avp Это SQL, а вы программист — как-нибудь с модификацией запроса справитесь. ;) / Ваши данные не звучат убедительно. Для полноты картины нужно полноценное сравнение поведения до и после переезда. / Всё, я чуть менее, чем полностью, эвей на неделю.

Comment: @Discord, ну, часто каждый видит то, что хочет увидеть. Будем надеяться, что найдутся чуть более заинтересованные чем мы люди и прояснят картину.

Comment: @avp про ряд `tiny,small,normal,large,huge` - подходящий вопрос для http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NickVolynkin, во-первых, ну не лазить же по всем форумам (никакого времени на работу не останется), а во-вторых, я все же намного комфортней себя чувствую в родной языковой среде. Так что, придется пользунам привыкать к чему-то вроде tiny/tiny+/small-/small/small+ ...  и т.п.

Comment: @avp, как идея: tiny, very small, small, not so small, normal, big, large, huge, gigantic. Альтернативно, tiny, very small, small, smallish, normal, big, bigger, huge, gigantic.

Но если интересует мнение настоящих носителей языка, то конечно надо на english.s-e.com

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, спасибо.

Comment: запрос, демонстрирующий насколько обновляются ряды людей, которые на вопросы отвечают https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/341457/active-experts-100-burnout-rate-after-a-year-by-default?year=2015&week=26&comparisonGap=1.0#resultSets (в 2015 ~75% осталось)

Comment: Имеет ли смысл переименовать заголовок в текущее название ruSO?

Comment: @edem, imho не надо

Comment: Ну хотя бы пояснение, что ответы, начиная С, относятся уже к ruSO.

Answer (score 9):

Да нет никакой проблемы. Ну или она сильно преувеличена. У большинства "потерявших интерес" топовых пользователей график набора репутации выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всегда есть резкий набор сразу после регистрации, потом резкий спад. Я просмотрел топ (насколько можно вообще называть пользователей с 7к репутации топом) - почти все старожилы перестали отвечать на вопросы еще в 2012-2013 году. Т.е. топ "ушел" еще пока хэшкод был хэшкодом.

Есть пару человек с плавным набором, который продолжается до сих пор - но это скорее исключение.

Comment: Вы выбрали участника, который очень долго возглавлял топ, но действительно давно тихо ушел.

Comment: Покликал, пара человек -- это сильное преувеличение, но во многом Вы правы, активность может быть половины топа упала до перехода в СО.

Comment: Вот такого ответа я ждал, спасибо.

Comment: @avp половина топа - это и есть те 18 человек. я сам так "ушел" с трех форумов. и на msdn у меня кривая местной репутации выглядела точно так же.

Answer (score 8):

Как мне кажется, проблема достаточно глубока.

#### Взгляд со стороны

Сообщество - это живой организм. Три месяца назад мы сделали серьезную операцию, перешли на новую платформу. Не желая терять время, воодушевленные переменами, мы двинулись дальше, начали менять правила сообщества.

Таким образом, я не считаю, что проблема в угасании интереса, мы с вами не могли потерять интерес к программированию и общению на русском языке за эти три месяца. Думаю, проблема именно в изменении правил сообщества. Поменяв их, мы изменили правила игры. Мне кажется, некоторые знатоки взяли паузу, чтобы понять, что именно представляет из себя обновленный ХэшКод - Stack Overflow на русском.

Более того, я как участник сообщества вот уже длительное время пытаюсь взглянуть “со стороны” на проект. Я вижу, что мы по чуть-чуть теряем что-то очень важное, ту идею, ради которой был запущен проект, ради которой мы с вами день за днем вот уже более четырех лет делимся знаниями с коллегами на сайте. Для меня крайне важно, что этот вопрос подняли именно вы, один из тех участников, заложивших фундамент сообщества. Как ни странно, некоторые “старички” проекта говорят примерно о том же.

#### Так в чем же все-таки проблема?

На мой взгляд, проблема в том, что под давлением авторитета англоязычного проекта мы насильно пытаемся стать “такими же”. Мы видим, что Stack Overflow на английском крайне полезен, эффективен и популярен среди разработчиков во всем мире. Мы копируем все, что попадает под руку, пытаясь сделать наш русскоязычный островок знаний таким же значимым, но, сами того не осознавая, становимся хуже, а не лучше.

Позвольте мне кратко пояснить, что я имею в виду.

#### Идеология Stack Overflow на английском и Stack Overflow на русском

*Давайте очень кратко рассмотрим, как была запущена англоязычная версия сайта.* В Интернете существовало большое количество дискуссионных (стандартных) форумов, но найти решение задачи “по работе” на таких площадках не представлялось возможным (на самом деле все то же самое, как и в Рунете). Сталкиваясь с задачей, решение которой мы не знаем, мы обращались к коллегам в устной форме. А если знающих коллег нет? В этом случае тебя ждет нервотрепка и океан унижения.

Решая эти и другие задачи, Stack Overflow стал тем самым местом, где программисты со всего мира делятся друг с другу прикладными знаниями без шума, ругани и спама и, что самое важное, эффективно. Теперь нам не надо работать в Google, чтобы иметь возможность перенять знания, например, Джона Скита, ведь с Stack Overflow мы можем общаться с лучшими умами современности и работать в небольшой компании из дома.

*Как же был запущен ХэшКод? В чем отличие?* Хотя ХэшКод был запущен тогда, когда Stack Overflow еще не был мировым стандартом, мы не планировали каким-либо образом создать конкурирующий продукт. Наоборот, мы хотели улучшить существующий, дополнить недостающей русскоязычной частью. Собравшаяся группа энтузиастов “русскоязычного Stack Overflow” прекрасно знала о существовании англоязычной версии, более того, большинство из нас отлично знали английский.

*Так в чем же все-таки суть проекта в этом случае?* Мы хотели создать базу решений прикладных задач, которые возникали в повседневной деятельности, в первую очередь для себя, чтобы не возвращаться к одним и тем же вопросам повторно. Конечно же, мы были рады, когда собранные нами знания могли помочь кому-либо, помимо нас.

С появлениям вопросов от других пользователей мы не могли оставлять их без ответа, мы старались помочь, и не только своей профессиональной экспертизой, но и многими повседневными знаниями, например, подсказкой того, как правильно искать информацию в поисковике. Мы никогда не грубили и не отправляли в “Google”, мы хотели создать окружение, в котором знатоки, Мастера своего дела, могли делиться знаниями с коллегами в то же время, когда сами познавали мир.

#### Сообщество

Развиваясь, Stack Overflow становился все сложнее и сложнее. Чем больше участников сообщества, тем важнее (и, конечно же, сложнее) их организация. Stack Overflow на английском потребовался не один год, чтобы выработать существующие правила. С течением времени и изменением правил менялись и сами вопросы: то, что было приемлемо раньше, становилось недопустимым.

Многие пользователи, не видевшие весь процесс эволюции проекта, могут иметь неполное представление о том, что именно такое Stack Overflow и почему он такой, а не другой, зачем вообще он нужен. Как результат, они часто судят о Stack Overflow на других языках с позиции сегодняшнего Stack Overflow, где задается по 9 000 вопросов в день. Отчасти мы стали пленниками именно такого суждения.

Рассуждая о сообществе, можно видеть, что Stack Overflow на английском отличается от Stack Overflow на любом другом языке настолько сильно, что некоторые правила “большого” Stack Overflow не могут быть применимы.

#### Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?

[Хотя основные логические выкладки уже записаны в соответствующем вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/), наблюдая за проектом со стороны, я задался вопросом, “*Что для **меня** значит Stack Overflow на русском?*”, “*Зачем **мне** нужен Stack Overflow на русском?*”, “*Зачем **мне** нужен Stack Overflow на русском, ведь я свободно говорю на английском?*”. Я не мог найти ответ (помимо приведенных в вопросе) до тех пор, пока не вспомнил, зачем вообще был запущен ХэшКод - для того, чтобы создать базу решений прикладных задач, которая позволит *мне* делать *мою* работу быстрее, и базу эту я пишу *сам* и *для себя*. После все “зачем“ пропали, а нужда [обращаться к бесспорно верным логическим выкладкам вышеупомянутого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/) пропала.

Мое понимание (как участника сообщества) значимости Stack Overflow на русском вернулось к исходному. Для меня Stack Overflow на русском - это крайне необходимое, важнейшее дополнение Stack Overflow, без которого мир не полон.

#### Что делать дальше?

Мне кажется, что пришло время сделать шаг назад, вернуться к той движущей силе, которая превратила любовь инженеров к свой профессии в Stack Overflow на русском.

Чтобы сделать Stack Overflow на русском лучшим местом для получения ответа по программированию и системному администрированию, нам следует:

- пересмотреть все правила, описанные в справке;
- выдвинуть новые идеи, касающиеся функционала управления сообществом (например, изменить текущие причины закрытия, которые никак не отражают суть);
- непрерывно обучать новых пользователей правилам общения на сайте за счет внесения улучшающих правок и поясняющих комментариев;
- продолжать делиться знаниями с коллегами.

Подчеркну: сообщество Stack Overflow на русском - это мы, пользователи. Именно мы сами должны выработать правила общения на сайте. Подготовленные переводчиком тексты лишь признаны послужить временной “заглушкой”. Если вы видите, что сообществу следует исправить что-либо, просто задайте вопрос на Мете.

В завершение я еще раз хотел бы подчеркнуть, что Stack Overflow на русском - это мы с вами. Именно от наших действий зависит, как будет развивать сообщество и отчасти вся индустрия в целом, сможем ли мы своей добродетельностью сделать пространство русского языка лучше.

Отвечая злом на зло, мы породим лишь зло. Таким образом, если вы видите, что кто-то из пользователей вредит развитию русскоязычного сообщества программистов, пожалуйста, начните публичную дискуссию на Мете, ведь, возможно, автор злодеяния даже не догадывается, что делает что-то не так.

Мы вместе создали остров знаний. Переход на новую платформу дал нам “корабли”, чтобы мы могли свободно “перевозить” ресурсы. Но только мы решаем, куда нам двигаться, только мы ответственны за то, насколько хорошо живется на нашем острове знаний. Мне кажется, становится совершенно ясно, что правила жизни, принятые на материке, не работают в климате нашего острова.

Comment: Много воды, по сути изменение правил. Вот только какие менять предлагаете и как? Нужна конкретика, потому что каждый понимает ваши слова по-своему.

Comment: Подождем конкретного плана.

Answer (score 8):

Выскажусь как один из старожилов прожекта и пока еще модератора (пока еще).

Я уже в оффлайне обсуждал проблему с несколькими другими старожилами. Действительно налицо падение интереса к проекту со стороны старожилов. Сразу оговорюсь: возможно что это не есть плохо - проект развивается появляются другие люди/лидеры, и старожилам наверное стоит уйти в сторону и посмотреть во что это выродится (или превратится).

Теперь к сути - почему старожилам проект становится неинтересным:

1. В варианте классического Хэшкода, проект таки был местом встречи программистов. Можно было обсуждать проблемы не только связанные непосредственно с кодированием, но также проблемы образования, учебы, работы и нытья (как же без этого).
2. Вторым по важности было то, что в проекте преобладали именно классические программисты С/С++/Java, а не верстальщики, дизайнеры и проч. публика из области `html/css` и примыкающие к ним `PHP/JS` (ничего личного)

С момента перехода на рельсы SO ситуация поменялась. Вдруг стали под запретом темы связанные с обучением/работой/нытьем. Далее проект заполонили люди из области верстки `html/css/php/js` - шум создаваемый этим братством не могут перебить такие уважаемые эксперты в этой области как @knes @lampa - к сожалению не могут.

Не знаю насколько все это связанные вещи, но новые лидеры (назовем их так), стали активно банить новичков и вообще все околозапретные темы, применяя в общем то законные меры типа *замораживание*, *закрытие* и *минусование* вопросов. Классический пример [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431196/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-sqlite/431229#431229) - 3 минуса + закрытие с заморозкой за в общем то нормальный вопрос (плюс парочка издевательских комментариев). За что? Я такого подхода не понимаю и не разделяю. Я хоть и модератор наделенный разными полномочиями, но не все могу. В какой-то момент я просто устал бороться с такими выходками и скоро наверное совсем прекращу борьбу.

Еще раз повторю - возможно все к лучшему, может так и надо. Но наверное уже без меня.

Как то так.

**Update (4 года спустя)**

Ресурс катится в никуда. ruSO превратился в унылое болото, в котором преобладают новички/школяры, которые приходят задать 1 невнятный вопрос получить/не получить ответ и исчезнуть надолго/навсегда. Не скажу за все категории, но Java/Android/Kotlin - явно переживают не лучшие времена. Типичный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026120/android-project). Куда подевались прежние жаркие и остроумные дискуссии, отличные вопросы и не менее отличные ответы? Похоже все мало-мальски значимые контрибуторы пересели на [discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) или подобные ресурсы.

Ни к чему не призываю, просто высказываю свое мнение.

Comment: Нет, Бармалей, это не к лучшему, так не надо. / Надо стремиться к высокому уровню понимания (а в идеале развитию) IT (хотя бы и для ограниченной группы), а не к растолковыванию общедоступных материалов (да, в рамках существующей схемы (в т.ч. движка) это очень сложно).

Comment: То, о чём Вы говорите это типичное не понимание того, чем является SO и почему он оставил позади форумы. Это на форумах происходит обсуждение и переливание из пустого в порожнее. SO сделан для вопросов/ответов. А не для посиделок. Касательно указанного в ответе вопрос(по Андроид). "что тяжело было просто спросить что надо мальчику?" - это, по Вашему, подобающий пример комментария? "Мальчику". Вы серьёзно? Папочка? В Вашем комментарии конкретное пренебрежение, учитывая то, что Вы даже примерно не знаете человека, который задал вопрос. И, да, этот вопрос дискуссионный и лежит за пределами SO.

Comment: @ixSci ну конечно за 5 лет я так ничего и не понял :) Мне в общем то без разницы маркетингово/финансовые изыски админов форума. Для меня хэш в первую очередь место обсуждения/дискуссии, узнавания нового сеяния доброго/вечного (как это ни банально звучит). Касательно комментария про мальчика - да это у меня такой стиль - поцанчег :) я по крайней мере не прячусь в отличие от многих за безликим аватаром. Так что давайте не будем ля-ля. И да, кстати, мальчику то реально я помог, а не вы и подобные им своими минусами и каментами.

Comment: SO это не ХэшКод. Я не знаю чем был ХэшКод, но судя по стенаниям, он мало чем отличался от обычного форума. От SO был только стиль отображения, как я понимаю. Так вот, в SO другая философия. И её либо надо принимать, либо не принимать. Но навязывать философию форума, сервису ответов на вопросы - глупо. Из этого ничего не выйдет. SO просто не предназначен для этого. Движок другой. Касательно помощи - да, помогли, видимо. Только вот вопрос там на грани фола, и на такие вопросы отвечать на SO не принято.

Comment: @ixSci не надо мне рассказывать что есть SO, я там как можете видеть, также достаточно давно и прекрасно знаю и понимаю как он устроен и что он есть. SO также превратился в тусовку где тусуется народ в основном с репой выше нескольких тысяч. Сейчас с нуля набрать в стэке 5-6 тысяч уже сложно - забросают сразу же. Хэш еще не набрал такую критическую массу юзеров и автоматом прикладывать туда тот же стиль не есть верно. Вот когда 10-тысячников будет не 20 человек, как сейчас а несколько сот вот тогда то можно будет - пока рано.

Comment: @ixSci: en.SO — это не хэшкод. А вот ru.SO — это во многом именно Хэшкод, нравится нам это или нет. И если мы просто так выкинем с ru.SO весь Хэшкод, много ли останется? А насчёт навязывания философии — мы, сообщество, определяем тут философию. Поэтому это как раз вы хотите поменять её.

Comment: @VladD, использование базы hashcode не означает, что новый ресурс должен перенимать "дух" его. Я не знаю как правильно, я лишь высказываю своё мнение. Если мне надо пообщаться с народом, я пойду на винград и пообщаюсь, я полагаю у многих тут есть форумы, откуда они пришли. Просто на мой взгляд, "камерная" атмосфера форума не должна быть перенесена на такой ресурс как SO, это его погубит. Лучше пусть это будет бездушная машина, которая даёт ответы, чем ещё одно место, где местные "гуру" будут мерятся толщиной репутации.

Comment: @VladD, "мы сообщество" - это кто? Если Вы не заметили, то взгляды на то, как должен развиваться ресурс тут расходятся и явно не в пользу старого ХэшКод, как показывают голоса в опросах

Comment: @ixSci: «меряться толщиной репутации» — это упрёк мне? Я не замечал за собой фраз наподобие «да у вас даже 5К нет, что вы знаете вообще». По поводу атмосферы, мне кажется, что её можно сохранить. И нужно. Поэтому я бы ставил вопрос по-другому — не «как убить старую атмосферу», а «как сделать, чтобы обсуждения не мешали читателю». Потому что мне лично старая атмосфера нравилась.

Comment: @VladD, никаких упрёков. Я вообще говорил про форумы - русскоязычные форумы не дружелюбны к новичкам. "Ахаха нуб припёрся, ну ладно, я тебе сейчас с барского плеча дам треть ответа, а ты потом остальное сам додумай, я ведь ГУРУ, не зря у меня в карме 100500 плюсов". Мне бы не хотелось такого здесь. И если придерживаться строгой философии вопрос/ответ, то такому попросту не будет здесь места. В противном случае будут "гуру снисходящие до ответа", а это плохо кончится.

Comment: @ixSci: Это мы. @avp, @Barmaley, @klopp, @Nicolas, @Athari, @PashaPash, вы и все, кого не назвал (и перед кем за это извиняюсь). И эти самые _мы_ определяют то, что здесь хорошо и плохо, модно или отстой. Если вы хотите переубедить нас, не прячьтесь за спиной en.SO («на SO так положено, что обсуждать»), а просто возьмите и _переубедите_ всех _нас_.`

Comment: @ixSci: Да, _дружелюбная_ атмосфера нужна, я обеими руками за. Но ведь «обсуждения по душам» не исключают вежливости? / А отношение к топикстартеру слабо коррелирует с кармой, как мне показалось.

Comment: @VladD, у меня создаётся впечатление, что в русскоязычном сегменте "обсуждение по душам" с новичками это всегда хамство. Лично я против любого неформального общения в пределах сервиса ответа/вопросов. Для этого тут есть чаты. Но я *никого* переубеждать не намерен, моя заинтересованность в ресурсе не простирается настолько далеко, чтобы заниматься его изменением. Тут моя позиция довольно проста: пока меня устраивает, я нахожусь на ресурсе, как надоест/перестанет устраивать, просто уйду по-английски.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, вот и вы угрожаете хлопнуть дверью. Мне кажется, что обсуждение по душам и давление на новичков — это совершено разные вещи. Я стараюсь отвечать правильно не только по содержанию, а и по форме. А «по душам» относится скорее к вопросам, выпадающим из жёстко понимаемого _некоторыми участниками_ формата.

Comment: @VladD, упаси Бог, я ничем не угрожаю. Я просто пояснил моё отношение - почему я не хочу заниматься переубеждением. Вы меня просто не так поняли.

Comment: @VladD, Вы пишете «давление на новичков», как будто это однозначно плохая вещь. Общество давит на всех нас, в реале или в Интернете — не важно. И так устроен мир, ибо сообщества, где каждому индивиду позволено делать что угодно, не выдерживают конкуренции.

Comment: @Barmaley всё плохо, а делать-то что?

Comment: @Suvitruf, а вдруг, если **убрать вахтеров** (и забить на обиженных), все само собой постепенно  наладится? Конечно, старики не вернутся, но вырастет новое адекватное поколение

Comment: @avp так вахтёры вроде многие и так поливали уже. Так что, проблема не в них. Мне видится, что просто нету курса развития ресурса, он сам по себе худо-бедно болтается.

Comment: @Suvitruf, хотите сказать, что на тревоги перестали реагировать, а дискуссии в комментариях теперь приветствуются? (только никто про это уже не помнит и поэтому сайт напоминает кладбище)

Comment: @avp реагирую. Я никогда не был против дискуссий в комментариях. И комментарии не сношу в этом плане, максимум в чат переношу, если их >20.

Answer (score 5):

ИМХО. Для меня Stack Overflow - это база знаний, лаконично оформленная в виде "вопрос - ответ". Я зарегистрировался всего пару месяцев назад после того как нашел через поисковик ответ на вопрос по программированию. Ответ был короток, но содержателен, -  я не только получил то, что искал, но и приобрел дополнительные знания, которые сразу и применил в решении задачи.

Читая форумы по программированию, я далеко не всегда находил действительно качественные ответы; кроме того, иногда там отвечают что-то вроде "гугл в помощь". На SO сама форма "вопрос - ответ" и модерация сообществом исключают весь тот бред, который можно увидеть, например на Mail.Ru (вспомнил его, так как там структура ресурса похожа на SO и его в других ответах упоминали).

Короче говоря, ru.SO имеет много преимуществ по сравнению с другими ресурсами, главные на мой взгляд:

1. Форма "вопрос - ответ"
2. Модерация сообществом на основе репутации (всякий бред отметается быстро)
3. Много знающих людей, которые могут ответить на большинство вопросов.

Именно 3 пункт на мой взгляд весьма важен, ради него тут большинство людей, задающих вопросы. Именно команда профессионалов дает SO преимущество, делает его не похожим на остальные ресурсы.

Что касается конкретных правил оформления и содержания вопросов, то они не являются залогом успеха SO. Хотя они, безусловно, приносят пользу,  некоторые из них все же надо менять. Конкретное предложение:

> Отменить пункт, запрещающий спрашивать о библиотеках кода, книгах и прочих ресурсах.

Причины:

1. На SO самые знающие люди - кто как не они могут посоветовать что-либо дельное или поделиться своими наработками.
2. Поиском библиотеки могут заниматься многие люди, поэтому ответы будут служить источником знаний и в будущем.
3. Всем нравится [этот список книг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)
4. Мой личный пример: искал библиотеку для работы с djvu на .NET, был уверен что нет ничего (бесплатного по крайней мере), но потом нашел то, что нужно. И знаете где? На [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462112/c-sharp-opensource-djvu-library) . И да : этот вопрос там закрыт (что однако не сделало его менее ценным).

Comment: Только важно понимать, что так важный пункт 3) может являться всего лишь следствием (побочным продуктом) активности "знающих людей". И их мотивация к ответам часто (imho) обусловлена вовсе не стремление помочь конкретному автору вопроса или абстракным (хотя и общественно полезным) *наполнием базы знаний*. Резюме -- **если им не будет здесь интересно, они потихоньку разбегутся** (общий уровень  приблизится к Mail.ru)

Answer (score 5):

За несколько месяцев, проведенные здесь, я вижу явный разрыв целей активных участников\администрации и собственно наполнения ресурса.

Цели администрации (как я ее понимаю) - создать ресурс с быстрым поиском верного решения появившейся нестандартной проблемы, либо квалифицированной помощью в случае отсутствия готового решения и последующего его переиспользования. Некоторая база знаний по нестандартным ситуациям для квалифицированных специалистов в своей области, которые делятся друг с другом неочевидными моментами в процессе разработки и не должны тратить много времени на решение этих проблем.

Не могу говорить за все разделы, я их не читаю, но вот по android-разработке, к которой я имею интерес и сопутствующим темам ( Java Gradle IDE и тд.) ситуация весьма печальная.

Ни по первой ни по второй цели не наблюдается каких то видимых продвижений.
По факту мы имеем 99% какого-то детского сада, вопросы задаются новичками, практически элементарные, решение которых лежит на поверхности при проявлении минимального усердия и хоть малейшего обучения делу, проявить себя в котором эти новички пытаются, однако не желая при этом хоть как то научиться тому, что собрались делать.
Нет, конечно это уже обсуждалось, кому то сложным кажется одно, кому то другое ... Но! , к примеру из недавнего - для чего оператор `new` ... согласитесь , это где то за гранью. Можно отвечать конечно, и я ответил, по возможности полно, в робкой надеже, что может человек попробует - у него получится и будет больше самостоятельно обучаться.

Проблема все же мне видится не совсем в этом. Проблема в том, что ресурс неуклонно превращается в начальную школу для лентяев, которые не хотят что то узнать самостоятельно, самые основы разработки - пусть мне дядьки персонально для меня разжуют, чего я буду время за книжками проводить.
Ну и вот, такие вопросы и ответы имеют практически **нулевую ценность для специалиста**, найти именно на русском оверфлоу решение реальной трудной проблемы почти всегда невозможно.

Можно утешиться тем, что новичкам тоже нужны ответы и они их найдут здесь, НО! и тут проблема. Новички эти **патологически не хотят читать, а тем более искать**, он заходит - сразу пишет, чего ему не понятно, не пытаясь посмотреть, что возможно ответ уже есть и ждет его. Конечно, ведь его вопрос такой уникальный и важный, некогда искать решение, надо быстрее спрашивать и пусть специально для меня, в сотый раз, разжуют одно и то же, то , что написано в любом мало-мальски годном учебнике... Да, пометить, как копия, это все понятно.

Я говорю о общей тенденции, что ни одна из целей этого ресурса не достигается и это печально.

Действительные специалисты, как правило не испытывают языковой барьер и находят решение на более серьезных ресурсах, как английски оверфлоу.
Новички не хотят использовать этот ресурс, неуклонно превращающийся в справочник начинающего лентяя-разработчика, как собственно справочник, а скорее, как персональный бесплатный консультационный пункт не читавшего ничего очередного "творца" шедевра.

Все это усугубляется тем, что я , например, не вижу какого то разумного решения сложившейся ситуации. Потеря интереса связана, по моему мнению и с тем, что в один прекрасный момент становится просто не интересно цитировать того же Эккеля, а читать "вопросы" иной раз без нервных судорог невозможно, приходиться принимать меры для того, чтобы успокоится, а кому это надо? сознательно портить себе настроение, чтобы потом его восстанавливать ...

**update**: Nicolas Chabanovsky попросил оформить в виде отдельного дискуссионного вопроса:

[Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/616/177345)

Comment: "Действительные специалисты, как правило не испытывают языковой барьер и находят решение на более серьезных ресурсах, как английски оверфлоу." - да.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Какие-то конструктивные идеи (пусть даже радикальные) есть?

Answer (score 4):

Пишу с мобилы, не могу побороть желание высказаться.

Качество у контента такое же, вопросы такие же, юзеры такие же. Да, теперь из-за минусов и закрытий всё это стало заметно, но ничего по сути не изменилось. Вы помните сайт, которого не было. Откройте список старых вопросов и убедитесь. Тот же самый мусор, даже хуже, потому что его никто не чистит.

Хотите флудить? Идите на форум, идите на Тостер, идите на Ответы@Mail.ru. Для вас ресурсов не хватает что ли?

Проблемы отсутствия отвечающих по популярным темам нет. За шанс ответить на вопрос драка. Хотите идти — идите, без вас сайт не загнётся.

А теперь по делу. Причину закрытия вопросов про выбор надо переформулировать, чтобы нельзя было закрывать нормальные детальные вопросы. На большом СО есть перегиб, не надо его копировать.

Вопросы про работу и прочий флуд, который для каждого юзера уникальный, не нужны. Точка.

Проблема не с топами, а с задающими вопросы. Их банально нужно больше. Чтобы это изменилось, нужны перекрёстные ссылки и прочий СЕО. Ждём.

Больше не вижу, что обсуждать. Хватит ныть, займитесь полезным делом.

---

**Обновление (4 года спустя)**

От лица примкнувших к свалившим... Сваливание старичков и падение статистики — нынче научно наблюдаемое явление. Достаточно посмотреть [статистику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) или заглянуть в чаты. Всё не так радужно и на большом SO, но на RuSO скатывание по большему числу параметров.

И хоть причины сваливания условных бармалеев и условных дискордов несколько отличаются, успехи работы партии налицо.

Удачи выжившим. Перспективы нет, но вы держитесь.

Comment: На деле я вижу, что есть туча вопросов, на которые можно и нужно отвечать, а вместо этого тупо их закрытие и минусование. Да есть некая толкучка за ответы на хорошие вопросы - не отрицаю, но нет толкучки за то чтобы г*венные вопросы превратить в нормальные вопросы - проблема в этом. Многие хотят по быстрому срубить на элементарных ответах, но не заботятся о том, чтобы плохие вопросы превратить в нормальные.

Comment: "Драка за шанс ответить..." -- это просто смешно. Что мешает дать еще один ответ? Может ничего своего нет (знания только из гугла?) вот добавить и нечего. / А что же нужно для появления *хороших вопросов*? Очевидно, что люди (уже достаточно грамотные). Почему они не появляются (или не задерживаются)? IMHO потому, что не видят тут достойного для себя контингента (т.е. достаточного количества ответов, которые с разных сторон разбирают вопросы (*следствие из правил, требующих однозначности ответа*)) с которым было бы интересно пообщаться на темы любимого программирования.

Comment: @barmaley Если видите заминусованными и закрытыми достойные спасения вопросы, кидайте ссылки, например, в чат - обсудим. Участвуйте в жизни сайта не только модераторскими инструментами, всё в ваших руках.

Comment: @avp Кто может хорошо отвечать - редко задаёт вопросы. В относительном отношении качество выше оригинального СО не поднять, надо поднимать всё абсолютно.

Comment: @Discord проблема в том, что я не могу сидеть постоянно на сайте. У меня в оффлайне туча своих дел. Я когда заскакиваю на сайт и вижу троллинг вопроса или нечто подобное то обычно кидаю пару комментов или просто переоткрываю вопрос и ухожу. Новичку ведь достаточно получить один-два минуса и он скорее всего уже никогда больше не вернется - никогда, проблема в этом. Обсуждать можно долго, но те кто минусует бездумно их много, очень много.

Comment: @Discord, возможно я ошибаюсь, но думаю, что реально, сами по себе ответы являются целью лишь для немногих отвечающих. Обычно она в чем-то другом. И если это другое (возможно ясно и не осознаваемое самим человеком) не достигается, то интерес будет быстро утерян. Большой SO на 2 порядка (113103 против 759 страниц с участниками) больше ru.SO. Вот там теперь и работает чистое Q&A (эти A создают именно те относительно немногие, для которых почему-то важно *просто отвечать*). / (Неужели Вам приятно отвечать на вопросы, получая взамен лишь обезличенные оценки?)

Comment: @avp Мой ответ на вопрос, зачем я здесь, в соответствующей теме. ;)

Comment: @Discord, ага, прочел. Считаете текущее состояние соответствует желаемому?

Comment: @avp Это не хорошо и не плохо. Так есть. Чтобы было лучше, нужно больше задающих вопросы, тогда будет больше хороших вопросов (и, соответственно, ответов) в абсолютнои исчсислении. Этот подход мне видится самым эффективным, потому что запас огромнейший. Разведение соплей вокруг "раньше трава была зеленее" или "давайте флудить, чтобы привлечь юзеров" — контрпродуктивно. / Я на сайте благодаря геймификации в том числе. Да, мне ужасно нравятся бесполезные циферки, которые говорят о моей крутизне и пользе окружающим. Просто отвечать, скоре всего, мне было бы скучно. А похоливарить — на форум.

Answer (score 2):

OK.

Я - klopp.

Только не спрашивайте о происхождениии этого ника, он зародился ещё в те времена, когда были модемы на 2400 и скорость набора рабочей рукой имела значение :)

Да, я срывался пару раз, в последний меня забанили. Сейчас, вроде, отпустили, но смысл?

До кучи: разлогиниться у меня так и не получилось, пришлось заводить новый аккаунт. Но и в нём я не вижу явно обозначенной кнопки "выход".

Возвращаясь к вопросу "зачем вы здесь". Для меня в первую очередь - это поупражняться в решении простых задачек. Ну, чтобы не расслабляться.

Но у всяких упражнений есть предел. Вот до этого упора меня хватает, а дальше - зачем?

Пользительность каждого ресурса определяется простым соотношением: отдал/получил. В чём бы оно не выражалось, для меня оно уже уходит в минус. А значит, и тратить силы/время смысла нет.

И да, всякие фантики типа реп, плюсов или минусов, мне настолько по барабану...

Comment: Возвращайтесь! Старая гвардия может ведь. Плюс думаю несложно объединить экаунты, если шепнуть на ухо администрации.

Comment: Старая, ага... Но не вижу смысла. Простой баланс: а что взамен? Репофантики? Вопросы, которые было бы интересно иногда обсудить, тут под запретом. Начиная с банального поиска библиотек, и заканчивая обсуждениями чего  угодно: алгоритмы, реализации, да вообще всего, что не предполагает чёткого  "вопрос/ответ". Сама по себе организация ресурса этого не допускает. Что регулярно подтверждается руководящим составом :) А на свои вопросы  я быстрей ответы нахожу другими путями. Так смысл?

Comment: Ну, давайте попробуем ослабить запреты. Администрация вроде [не слишком против](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530/10105).

Comment: Смогу ли я после этого вставить в коммент полноценный, отформатированый код? Сможе те ли вы не ютиться в рамках, а ответить тоже полноценно, ещё более прекрасным кодом? Сможем ли мы вести дискуссию, которая не ограничена возможностями движка?Вряд ли.  Не  нужно выдаивать из сайта то, что он не может дать в принципе.

Comment: Хм. Зато сейчас есть чат, и нет лимита комментариев. В чате можно постить код, кстати. А вот за темы дискуссий можно и побороться. Так что что-то убавилось, что-то прибавилось.

Comment: Код можно вставлять в update в ответе. Основная проблема, как я ее теперь вижу -- отсутствие нотификации всех участников темы о каком-либо изменении в ней (сейчас в одном комменте можно указать только один ник). Поэтому коллективное творчество и пропадает. IMHO небольшая модификация движка (возможность подписаться на любое изменение в теме) могла бы сильно изменить ситуацию. / (klopp, поскольку Вы это увидите как автор ответа, отправлю весточку to @VladD)

Comment: Какие-то искусственные пути обхода ограничений. Да, и если вы уговариваете меня вернуться, то это возможно будет только тогда, когда клавиша "Ввод" в поле комментария будет делать то, что ей положено.

Comment: @avp, да дело не в уведомлениях даже (хотя, это важно). Вот что лично для меня было интересно, так это ваша реализация поиска счастливых билетов! И , кстати, ещё раз спасибо, такой шикарный пример выдали. Всё, с тех пор - ничего. Поболтать бы, бы вы б покритиковали, я б поспорил, подключились бы другие люди - таненбаум с линусом бы посмотрели в сторонке... Но - формат ресурса. А раз  так, ну и...

Comment: @avp Ну, что делать, у меня тоже был искусственный путь обхода границы в 4 комментария, основанный на баге в движке. А Enter в комментариях можно по идее перемапить юзерскриптом?

Comment: Ну, про искусственность таких ухищрений не поспоришь (конечно, уродливо). А формат сайта... Есть такое выражение -- "поступай как правильно и будь что будет". И еще одно -- "пока ты еще не все сделал на этой Земле -- осколки пролетят мимо". Я думаю, обида через некоторое время пройдет.

Comment: В общем, банальное действие UI мне стало интересно. Буду писать в FDA, или куда там принято.

Comment: Библиотеки, алгоритмы и реализации обсуждать можно и нужно, надо только задавать вопрос нормально, а не "что лучше". Сайт включает тематику Programmers.

Comment: Это исходя из всего вышесказанного Вы ведёте себя как подросток, у которого едва наступил препубертатный период и хамите всем пользователям в своих ответах?  Безусловно, мы будем очень по Вам скучать.

Comment: @Discord: Окей, а _вы_ сможете при случае _исправить_ пару вопросов, чтобы они вписались в тематику?

Answer (score 2):

Вот поэтому: всё что не угодило будет удалено.

> [image: всё что не угодило будет удалено.]

или, по меньшей мере, заминусовано

> [image: или заминусовано]

Comment: Второй ответ удалён, потому что он второй. Этот текст можно было доабавить в первый.  Касательно минусов - это мета, тут минусы ставятся весьма легко - это нормально.

Comment: Второй ответ удален, потому что автор издевается, выливает свою агрессию на сообществе, то есть ответ не конструктивный. не более. Любое _обоснованное_ мнение на Мете приветствуется.