# Нужно ли переводить или формировать FAQ for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка

[Актуальность перевода знаний уже обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/181472). Давайте теперь обсудим перевод и кристаллизацию мета-знаний, то есть знаний о StackExchange.

Есть достаточно большое собрание документов: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/296059). Он организован в виде вопроса-оглавления со ссылками на другие вопросы-темы, в которых есть ответы - подтемы.

На StackOverflow на русском языке уже есть метка [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), объединяющая полезные вопросы. Но единого оглавления вроде бы нет.

Вопросы:

- Нужно ли это оглавление нам, на русском языке?
- Целесообразно ли переводить и адаптировать вопросы из «FAQ for Stack Exchange sites»?

  - Если да, то какие наиболее актуальны?
- Или достаточно систематизировать те, которые естественным путем появляются здесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, прямой перевод публикаций о правилах ошибочен. В общих чертах я описывал причины в [этом ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/530/6).

Если коротко. Правила следует вводить ровно в тот момент, когда в них возникает необходимость.

Практика перевода/копирования правил Stack Overflow на английском порочна. Сталкиваясь с проблемой, участники начинают обдумывать, а как же её решить. В случае переводов, приходят на Мету, вместо диалога пользователи получают ссылку на перевод правила с английского (текст зачастую еще и не адаптирован). Как результат, нет ни согласия в сообществе, ни понимания самих правил.

Опыт англоязычного сообщества уникален. Очень здорово, что он есть. Но Stack Overflow на русском другое сообщество. Мы сами должны создать свой свод правил так, чтобы именно нам было приятно и полезно пользоваться ресурсом.

В свою очередь, мне кажется, что перевод информационных статей ([например](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/)) может быть отличной идеей на пути к пониманию тонкостей движка (многие из которых не очевидны) сообществом.

Comment: То есть информация - да, правила - разрабатываем сами. Понял. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно ли это оглавление нам, на русском языке?

**да**

> Целесообразно ли переводить и адаптировать вопросы из «FAQ for Stack Exchange sites»?

**нет**

> Если да, то какие наиболее актуальны?

**-**

> Или достаточно систематизировать те, которые естественным путем появляются здесь?

**да**

Comment: Там вот Nicolas Chabanovsky отмечает, что вопросы по движку сайта переводить есть смысл, а правила нужно разработать самостоятельно. Мне нравится такое разделение, выглядит рационально.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так создайте другой вариант ответа! «подсматривание» в оригинальный *faq*, мне кажется, подразумевается по умолчанию. только «инициатива», с моей точки зрения, целиком и полностью должна принадлежать «здешним» вопросам.

Comment: изменил ваш ответ, включил разделение между двумя группами.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно ли это оглавление нам, на русском языке?

**да**

> Целесообразно ли переводить и адаптировать вопросы из «FAQ for Stack Exchange sites»?

Обсуждения, касающиеся правил — **нет**. Можно задать здесь этот же вопрос, но переводить и, тем более, принимать ответы — нельзя. Мы — отдельное сообщество, и мы должны выработать собственные правила.

Информационные тексты по движку Stack Exchange — **да**.

> Если да, то какие наиболее актуальны?

Это нужно обсуждать отдельным вопросом или в чате.

> Или достаточно систематизировать те, которые естественным путем появляются здесь?

**да**.