# Как посмотреть статистику посещений, открытых/закрытых вопросов и принятых ответов?

Tags: поддержка, статистика

Интересуюсь статистикой уникальных посещений сайта, количеством заданных вопросов, принятых и закрытых ответов за последнее время. Создаётся впечатление, что ресурс медленно (а может быть и стремительно) теряет популярность. Понимаю, что многих данных у обычных пользователей быть не может, но всё таки...

Comment: С мобилы не очень удобно публиковать картинки, но лето в целом период спада посещаемости. Хотя с нового года до начала лета было резкое падение посещаемости, всего раза в два. Но это скорее всего из-за того что владельцы перестали закупать трафик и ресурс начал жить своей жизнью. А за всё лето в принципе картина никак не изменилась, как было 3 месяца назад, так сейчас и есть.

Comment: @aepot меняется ли соотношение заданных вопросов к отвеченным/закрытым?

Comment: Примерно коррелирует.

Comment: Уже было, и не раз: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10881 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8948 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7246 https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/526. Вопрос по статистике - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339