# Зачем нужен [stackoverflow]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, использование-метки

Нет, это не дубликат [Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/181472)

У нас есть метка [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow). **Зачем она нужна и к каким вопросам ее применять?**

Предположил, что метка предназначена для вопросов об англоязычном stackoverflow ([описание](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/48), [выдержка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/49)):

> Stack Overflow — популярная система вопросов и ответов о программировании, являющаяся частью сети Stack Exchange. Принятым языком общения является английский, но существуют варианты на других языках, в том числе на русском. Используйте эту метку для вопросов, связанных именно со Stack Overflow на английском языке.

Однако, правки были отклонены. Иного смысла для этой метки я придумать не могу. **Она не может обозначать StackOverflow на русском**, так как все ответы на meta.ru.stackoverflow.com относятся к этой теме — отмечать это отдельным образом нет смысла.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, она обозначает нечто общее, как минимум, для английского и русского сайта, а может быть и вообще для всей сети Stack Exchange.

Comment: Тогда нужно переименовывать в [meta-tag:stackexchange]. И даже тогда я не могу придумать адекватного применения для метки.