# Допустимо ли советовать человеку задавать узкоспециализированный вопрос на enSO или другом англоязычным сайте StackExchange?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы

Бывают задаются вопросы по узкоспецизированным темам. Допустим вопросы по [directx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directx) (кроме самых поверхностных вопросов и самоответов, в этой теме ответов нет). Бывает ещё больший хардкор: вопрос по третьесторонней .NET-обёртке [sharpdx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharpdx). И натыкаешься на очередной вопрос по узкой теме.

1. Уместно ли попросить автора перевести и задать этот же вопрос на enSO (или другом англоязычным сайте StackExchange, в данном случае [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) тоже будет уместен). А также бросить ссылку на заданный на других сайтах.
2. А также можно ли сказать сказать ему, что на это узкоспециализированный вопрос, поэтому ответа тут вряд ли дождёшься?

Comment: 2-е - точно лишнее. понятие "узкой специализации" очень субьективно. Например, я пару раз отвечал на вопросы, у которых в комментариях была такая странная приписка - хотя никакой специфической специализации у меня нет :)

Comment: Конечно допустимо, сеть то одна

Answer (score 3):

Совет задавать вопрос на другом сайте сети Stack Exchange может быть понят двояко и отобьёт желание задавать вопросы на ruSO в принципе. Это не лучший вариант, т.к. без вопросов не могут появиться и ответы. Всё это довольно сильно коррелирует с вопросом о необходимости существования ruSO в принципе: 
[Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/176217)

Однако, если есть серьёзные основания (например, личный опыт) полагать, что на другом сайте Stack Exchange удастся гарантированно получить достойный ответ, то совет, конечно, уместен, так как поможет человеку быстрее решить проблему. Но здесь не стоит сбрасывать со счетов и потерю некоторой точности передачи (а то и вовсе искажения смысла) вопроса/ответа при переводе с/на английский язык.

В любом случае публикация вопроса в нескольких разных местах (при сохранении тематичности) будет увеличивать вероятность получения ответа на него, т.к. банально увеличит кол-во людей, которые смогут его прочитать.

Так же хочу заметить, что enSO далеко не является панацеей. Например, у меня есть [ряд вопросов](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3240681%20answers%3A0%20duplicate%3A0), которые я задавал на enSO и тем не менее всё равно не получал ответов. На текущий момент я считаю, что подобные вопросы лучше бы вовсе задавать на соответствующих тематических форумах (вне сети Stack Exchange). Например, по [gstreamer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gstreamer) на http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/, 
а по [с++builder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2bbuilder) на https://forums.embarcadero.com/. Но тем не менее всегда [есть шанс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/516660/176217), что ответ будет получен и на ruSO. Всё таки русский язык для публикующих вопросы здесь родной и сформулировать вопрос и понять ответ проще на том языке, который чаще используешь.

Comment: Советовать задавать вопросы на других тематических форумах сильно кореллируется с необходимостью существование сети сайтов StackExchange в целом:).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov можно продолжить эту дискуссию, когда появится ru.gamedev.stackexchange по-русски :)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд эти вопросы тесно связаны - первое есть следствие второго.

1. Да, уместно. Если на данные момент на этом ресурсе нет людей способных помочь с вопросом, то лучше пусть человек хоть узнает о других местах где можно получить ответ чем не получит вообще ничего. Естественно такая отсылка должна быть в виде рекомендации или совета, что-то вроде:

   > Попробуйте задать этот вопрос на главном SO  или в гиттере проекта,
   >   потому-что ...
2. Можно, но лучше не употреблять обороты "ответа тут не дождешься", лучше сформулировать предложение без негативного отношения к ресурсу.

   > С узкоспециализированными вопросами вам быстрее помогут непосредственно на
   >   форуме/чате проекта или на main SO, так как ...

---

Update из-за комментария

Ни в коем случае не надо закрывать такие вопросы, возможно автор напишет ответ на свой вопрос и таким образом поможет сообществу. Или к сообществу присоединиться человек, способный ответить на вопрос по этой метке.

Comment: Только это не должно быть голосом за закрытие ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, конечно - нет никаких причин закрывать такие вопросы

Comment: @Qwertiy Не надо ничего закрывать, такие вопросы сами удалятся системой.

Comment: Я где-то видел, как подобное использовалось как причина закрытия...

Comment: Это что-то странное: как может закрываться вопрос, просто на основании узкой специализации?

Comment: @FoggyFinder "Ни в коем случае не закрывать" – с этим не согласен. Если есть адекватные причины: "дубликат", "неясен вопрос", "слишком широкий" и т.д., то почему нет?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov нет- нет, об этом речь и не идет

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, речь о формулировке "голосую за закрытие как не по теме, т. к. на него всё равно никто не ответит" и нескольких подобных с отсылками на superuser или другие сайты сети.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну имхо это просто неадекватные люди так делают:)

Answer (score -3):

Пусть все продолжают верить, что на Ru.SO есть специалисты. Не надо портить сказку и уменьшать посещаемость.

1. Перевести вопрос на английский.
2. Запостить вопрос на большом SO или специализированном подсайте.
3. Получить ответ.
4. Перевести ответ на русский.
5. Запостить ответ на Ru.SO.
6. Наловить уйму плюсов за умопомрачительные знания в области, в которой вы не разбираетесь.

Comment: Есть подозрение что плюсы набирает популярная тема.

Comment: @Aid Пусть все продолжают верить, что ответы на сложные вопросы по экзотическим темам приносят много плюсов. Не надо портить сказку и уменьшать число отвечающих.

Comment: Категорически не согласен.
1. Чтобы убедиться, что вопрос вообще адекватен надо попытаться вопроизвести проблему автора, что требует времени и усилий.
2. Затем желательно помониторить задавался ли вообще такой вопрос и не решён ли он где бы то ни было.
3. Перевести и задать вопрос. Для этого тоже желательно его понимать, а то можно и утерять смысл, переводя не понимая.
4. Чтобы понимать подходят ли ответы, тоже надо вопроизвести проблему, иначе как вы поймёте нормальные ли ответы. А вдруг их сразу несколько дадут? Тоже выйдет по-идиотски, если переводить всё подряд.

Comment: @Squidward По поводу "наловить уйму плюсов" я не знаю, зачем вы это пишите, я вроде адекватный человек:)

Comment: 1. Воспроизводить не нужно. 2. Разумеется, сначала надо попробовать скопипастить уже имеющийся ответ. 3. Понимать не нужно. 4. Копипастить всё, что-нибудь должно помочь. / Если вам скажут, что вы накопипастили какую-то фигню и накидают минусов, всегда можно удалить ответ, будто ничего и не было. Всегда так делаю.

Comment: ...Жжотенько :)

Comment: @Squidward А не проще ли попросить ТС задать вопрос на enSO и GameDev (в данном случае) раз так не хочется заморачиваться?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Ru.SO потеряет посетителя, а вы потеряете репу. Вы этого хотите?

Comment: @Squidward Хорошо, допустим вот есть [участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220874/dz-mir), у него все 6 вопросов по [tag:sharpdx]. Я думаю, если никто не среагирует (как обычно и происходит), то он и так догадается, что нет здесь знатоков по этой теме.:) Поэтому считаю, так хоть человек пойдёт верной дорогой.

Comment: @Squidward А если делать как вы говорите, то тогда уже надо отвечать на каждый вопрос участника (иначе вдруг мы его потеряем, какое горе). Кстати если перевести вопрос, то корректно было бы сделать ассоциацию, и тут участник может узнать наш суперсекрет.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov По-моему, этот участник стабильно отвечает на свои вопросы. Зачем ему помогать? Он сам прекрасно справляется. Это также говорит о том, что он не дурак, и уже заметил закономерность.

Comment: Вы предлагаете выдать чужой ответ за собственный? При переводе принято указывать автора оригинала.

Comment: @GreenDragon Если не указывать ссылку на оригинал, то ответ звучит круче, и плюсов достаётся больше. Главное не палиться. Если наедут, то добавить ссылку никогда не поздно.

Comment: ruSO в большинстве своем предназначен для тех, кто не знает английский, а про специальные технологии типы 1C это отмазки, метки для этого существуют.

Comment: `Наловить уйму плюсов за умопомрачительные знания в области, в которой вы не разбираетесь.` — не выйдет. CC BY-SA требует указания авторства и ссылки на оригинал. Тем, кто нарушает лицензию, можно бить линейкой по пальцам.