# Может ли ваш вопрос быть более уместным в другом месте?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, тематика

Как раз в тему соседнего вопроса [Допустимо ли советовать человеку задавать узкоспециализированный вопрос на enSO или другом англоязычным сайте StackExchange?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5435/178988) встретил проверку описания метки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/172337

> **Kali Linux** - это дистрибутив для тестирования на проникновение на основе Debian Linux. Раньше он назывался BackTrack Linux.
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: Большинство вопросов о Kali Linux не являются вопросами "программирования". Пожалуйста, подумайте, может ли ваш вопрос быть более уместным в другом месте.

Первая часть вроде ok, а вот что делать со второй?

Comment: А зачем вообще нужна эта метка? Это ж вроде просто коллекция разных утилиток для пентеста под Linux, уместнее использовать скорее метку Linux и, возможно, название софтины, о которой речь. Нет?

Comment: @D-side, возможно, [tag:kali-linux] — это в первую очередь название дистрибутива, наподобие [tag:ubuntu]. То есть, если эта метка не нужна, надо будет тереть *все* дистрибутивные метки.

Comment: @D-side, это же название дистрибутива - оно ни чем не хуже других ;)

Comment: Вторую часть убрать, очевидно. Почему вопросы про ubunti уместны, а про kali - нет?

Comment: @Nofate, во-первых, я так и сделал (правда, закомментировал, а не удалил), во-вторых, некое предупреждение там вполне может быть. Ну и наконец, ответы - в ответы ;)